# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    void function( int num);
    bool function1()const;
    virtual bool function2() const=0;
};

class B:public A {
public :
    bool function2()const;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    void (A::* p)(int)= &A::function;  //不是地址，而是一个指向成员函数的指针
    // Edit: Google translation of the above comment is
    // "Not address, but a pointer to a member function pointer"

    bool (A::* p1)()const =&A::function1;  // 指向成员函数的指针可以指向一个常量成员函数
    // Edit: Google translation of the above comment is
    // "Point to a member function pointer can point to a const member function"

    B b;
    A *a=&b;
    (a->*p1)();
    (b.*p1)();

    return 0;
}
```

but when I link it:

```
1>c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall A::function1(void)const " (?function1@A@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function _wmain
1>c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall A::function(int)" (?function@A@@QAEXH@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>c.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall B::function2(void)const " (?function2@B@@UBE_NXZ)
```

can you tell me why?

Comment: You are coding without indentation. It's hard to read.

Comment: I have indented the code using `astyle`. I've also translated the comments using Google, but they seem to not be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't implemented `A::function()`, `A::function1()`, or `B::function2()`.  You need to do that.

Comment: How could he have gotten to the level of implementing the complexities of inheritance without knowing that? I'm going to guess he didn't write this code?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but usually problems like this one happen because people copy/paste code they don't understand.

Comment: @Aerovistae That would be the reason for undefined symbols. Either they were never defined or the source file they reside in isn't being linked.

Comment: I expect you're right, yes, that the OP didn't write the code (at least not on his own).

Answer (score 1):

`A::function1`, `A::function` and `B::function2` are all declared, but never defined. You can't get a pointer to the function if it is not defined, where would it point?